# My app shows a white screen in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have created the foundations of an app that manages appointments and clients for my end user. I am now trying to test the app in the device emulator, however when the emulator opens, I discover that the screen is blank, apart from the ActionBar. I am failing to see what I am doing wrong, attached is the code for the activity:

```
package f454project.jack.chiropody;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ApptsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appts);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_appts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="f454project.jack.chiropody.ApptsActivity">
    <TabHost android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/tabHost"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Appointments"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Patients"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Help"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:orientation="vertical"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/listView"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:onClick="@string/title_activity_create_appt"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Because of your listview overwrites your tabhost. You should correct them.

Comment: There are many problems with your xml layout and it's not clear what you actually want it to look like

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have your tab contents added to the tabContent FrameLayout in the xml. This fixes most of your layout problems, however, the only thing that is actually visible is the button, and listView has a height of 0 because it has no contents. Let me know what you are trying to achieve here and I'll improve my answer.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="f454project.jack.chiropody.ApptsActivity">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Appointments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Patients"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Help"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="Create"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need it so that the tabs appear at the top, and have a method of switching between them. The "Create" button should launch a separate activity I am in the process of creating.